# Add new property to object collection based on condition with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects as such:

```
var data = [{ a: 1 },
            { a: 1 },
            { a: 2 },
            { a: 2 }];
```

How can I create, with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11), a new array just like `data` but for which we added a new property `b: 1` to each object that has the property `a` equal to `1`?

The new array should be like this:

```
var newdata = [{ a: 1, b: 1 },
               { a: 1, b: 1 },
               { a: 2 },
               { a: 2 }];
```

I guess we could combine both `_.assign` and `_.filer` but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with lodash via either `_.defaults` or `_.assign / _.assignIn / _.extend`:

```js
var data = [{ a: 1 },{ a: 1 },{ a: 2 },{ a: 2 }];

console.log(_.map(data, x => x.a==1 ? _.defaults(x, {b: 1}) : x))
console.log(_.map(data, x => x.a==1 ? _.assign(x, {b: 1}) : x))
console.log(_.map(data, x => x.a==1 ? _.assignIn(x, {b: 1}) : x))
console.log(_.map(data, x => x.a==1 ? _.extend(x, {b: 1}) : x))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the array and use a new property if the condition is `true`.

```js
var data = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 2 }],
    newData = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, o.a === 1 && { b: 2 }));

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with vanilla Javascript, this here works:

```
    var data = [{ a: 1 },
                { a: 1 },
                { a: 2 },
                { a: 2 }];

    var newData = [];

    newData =  data.reduce((acc, el) => {
        return el.a === 1 ?  acc.concat({a: el.a, b: 1}) :  acc.concat(el);
    }, []);

    console.log(newData);
// expected output: [{a: 1, b: 1},
//                   {a: 1, b: 1},
//                   {a: 2},
//                   {a: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a function with lodash by applying [`_.cond()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cond) to [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) with [`_.partialRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#partialRight).

Use [`_.matches()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#matches) to detect if the object has `a: 1` property, and [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#assign) `{ b: 1 }` if it does.

When `a` is not 1, use [`_.stubTrue()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#stubTrue) to always return the original object via [`_.identity()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#identity):

```js
var func = _.partialRight(_.map, _.cond([
  [_.matches({ 'a': 1 }), o => _.assign({}, o, { b: 2 })],
  [_.stubTrue,            _.identity]
]));

var data = [{ a: 1 },{ a: 1 },{ a: 2 },{ a: 2 }];
            
const result = func(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```